# want to get textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two textboxes which values are like:

```
312,315
```

```
315,313
```

I want to get a string with all the values, for example: `312,315,313` skipping existing  values in both fields.

My code:

```
var firstbox = $("#firstbox").val();
var secondbox = $("#secondbox").val();
var newvalue = $(firstbox).not(secondbox).get();
    console.log(newvalue);
```

But it's not working, how can I get my desired output using JQuery?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the two, joining them with a comma.
You would then have a comma delimited string, so you could split at the comma, remove any duplicate values, then rejoin the remaining values.

Something like this:

```
var firstbox = $("#firstbox").val(),
    secondbox = $("#secondbox").val(),
    boxes = firstbox + "," + secondbox,
    arr = boxes.split(","),
    res = [];

$.each(arr, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, res) === -1){
        res.push(el);
    }
});

$("#res").html(res.join(",").replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, ""));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/uV99u/)

Comment: if one textbox having no value then... mean one textbox is null then its show 212,215, extra comma in the last

Comment: I updated my fiddle and above demo to account for this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will give you a hint in the right direction:

```
// get comma seperated list of all values
var allValues = $('#firstbox').val() + ',' + $('#secondbox').val();

// make an array out of them
var allValuesArray = allValues.split(',');


// sort out repeated values
// by creating a new array 'distinctValues'
var distinctValues = [],
    currentValue,
    valuesLookup = {};

for (var i = allValuesArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    currentValue = allValuesArray[i];

    if (!valuesLookup[currentValue]) {
        valuesLookup[currentValue] = true;
        distinctValues.push(currentValue);
    }
}


// output the result to the console
console.log(distinctValues.join(','));
```